# How to change the SDom positiong in Datatable header?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I position the entries dropdown and search input option on top of the datatable? Both options are appearing on the left corner of the datatable. I want to show the entries on the left side and the dropdown on the right side.

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
```

Please advise how to align this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    "sDom": "l<'text-right'frti><'text-right'p>",
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: can you make sure that you have added all the required js files?Also, are you using any library like Bootstrap?

Comment: No , i'm not using Bootstrap and included all the jquery1.9.1 and jqueryui and datatable and css.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to your problem?